# Create DataFrame object from output of shell commands

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, pandas

I'm trying to create a Pandas DataFrame from the output of shell command. What I have tried works for something like `'ps aux | head -5'` but doesn't works for `'ls -la'`

This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
import subprocess
import pyperclip
import pandas as pd

a = subprocess.check_output("ps aux | head -5", shell=True)
pyperclip.copy(a)
pd.read_clipboard()
```

Output:

[image]

Although I can parse the output of various shell commands manually, I wanted to know if someone has already written a library or what would be the more Pythonic way for a command like `'ls -la'`?

Comment: don't parse ls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. I would perform the full `os.listdir()` followed by `os.stat()` to get file properties, and create a DF with that info. Python 3.5 also has a `os.scandir()` that directly returns a list of stat-like info.